# Jenkins Blue Ocean editing commit, message and changes

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-blueocean

I have a Jenkins pipeline that doesn't use git.  I would LOVE to use Blue ocean as an interface for the developers and QA members but since I'm not using git the interface is limited.  If I could edit the `commit` and `message` section it would take me a long long way.  Is there a way to do this?  or be able to change the run number to text would also be helpful. 
[image]

It would also be super helpful to be able to edit the changes within each build

[image]

Comment: did you ever find a solution to this?

Comment: No, I just stopped using blue ocean.  I'm sure it is better now, but when released it was limited.

Answer (score -2):

you can use this, to set the description and displayName:

```
currentBuild.displayName = "The name."
currentBuild.description = "The best description."
```

In order to use in a declarative pipleine, you need to wrap in a script - [jenkins script](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#script)